# Visual Studio 2015 Templates - Multi Item templates across multi projects

Tags: visual-studio, templates

We are trying to create an item template which consists of 3 files in 1 project and 1 file in another project (Both projects are in the same solution)

I can successfully generate a template for the 3 files in one project and then a seperate template for the other file but i cannot seem to find a way to combine these so when i add the template it adds files to the 2 projects.

Template 1 (in first project)

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
   <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>Template.ascx</DefaultName>
    <Name>Template Test</Name>
    <Description></Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="/Areas/Design/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/$fileinputname$.ascx" ReplaceParameters="true">SampleControlDesign.ascx</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="/Areas/Submit/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/$fileinputname$.ascx" ReplaceParameters="true">SampleControlSubmit.ascx</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="/Areas/Submit/Views/Render/$fileinputname$.ascx" ReplaceParameters="true">SampleControlRender.ascx</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Template 2 (in second project)

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>Template2.cs</DefaultName>
    <Name>Template 2</Name>
    <Description>Template for the creation of a controls domain model</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="" TargetFileName="/Models/Controls/$fileinputname$.cs" ReplaceParameters="true">SampleControl.cs</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```